# Finding order and degree of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The question was

> Find the sum of degree and order of the given DE (differential equation)$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3=0 $$

So we have that $$ \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3=c $$ whee c is some constant. For knowing the order and degree of a DE, it should not contain any arbitrary constant.
$$ 3\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)=0 $$ But this is not a polynomial form so degree shold not be defined. But the answer says that degree is 3 and order is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,y',...,y^{(n)})=0$, where $f(.)$ is a polynomial for multi-variables. *"Order"* refers to highest order of derivatives, $n$ in this case. 
*"Degree"* refers to the highest power of $y^{(n)}$ in $f(.)$.

For $\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^{3} =0$,

$$3\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^{2} y''=0$$
which has one repeated root $y'=0$.

Then $y'y''=0$, this is second order degree $1$ nonlinear ODE.

Comment: Could you please explain to me that why you have taken one y' out of diff equation ??

Comment: First of all, don't mess up with the characteristic equation of an ODE.  For example, $y''-2y'+y=0$, $$y(x)=ae^x+b\color{red}{xe^x}$$
in this case, the repeated root does alter the form of the general solution.  
However in $(y')^2=0$,  the repeating factor $y'$ doesn't give rise to an extra form in the solution.  That's why the degree still being $1$.

Comment: Thank you for clarification