# Can anyone give me examples of two non - linear differential equations --One of them is of degree 1 and another one has no degree?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Can anyone give me examples of two non - linear differential equations --One of them is of degree 1 and another one has no degree  ?

I have thought of some examples. Can you please correct me if I go wrong anywhere?

1) $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \cos (\frac{dy}{dx}) = 0$$_-This is an example of non-linear differential equation which has no degree.

2) $$ 3\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)=0 $$

This is an example of differential equation of degree 1.

I followed the following definition of degree and order to determine the same of the preceding differential equations.

Let $f(x,y,y',...,y^{(n)})=0$, where $f(.)$ is a polynomial for multi-variables. *"Order"* refers to highest order of derivatives, $n$ in this case. 
*"Degree"* refers to the highest power of $y^{(n)}$ in $f(.)$.

I can also say by this definition that the following differential equation is of degree 2 and  non linear.

$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x^2\frac{dy}{dx} -(\ cosx) \sqrt y = 2x^2 - 3x+4$$

Can somebody check if I  have gone wrong anywhere.  I have used the definition of order and degree from an answer [Finding order and degree of a differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615295/finding-order-and-degree-of-a-differential-equation) written by Ng Chung Tak

Comment: I meant that degree can not be determined. In (1)  we can not determine the  degree as we can not written it as polynomial..@5xum

Comment: Your second example is wrong, your ODE is not polynomial in all occurrences of $y$, and if you make it polynomial you change the ODE, introducing solutions that do not occur in the original version.

Comment: I did not get you....Can you please elaborate?@LutzL

Comment: which equation are you talking about? Is it the last one?@LutzL

Comment: If you talk about the last equation...Then I would say I know that I can not manipulate...But if I take the liberty of transformation so that all exponents be integers , then the degree becomes 2.. I followed this answer ---https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917742/find-order-and-degree-of-a-differential-equation

Comment: Sorry, yes, the last one, or the third example. Note in the linked answer the last note "Without forgetting that Eq.2 is not strictly equivalent to Eq.1", meaning it is not the same equation, you are making a statement about a different equation.